# HTTP interceptor display multiple message problem

Tags: c#, angular, http, asp.net-core

In my project (.net core 2.2 + angular 8).For showing one error HttpInterceptor  it works perfect,
 but for multiple messages it is also working but does not show proper error message.
I got something like that:

```
[object Object] One or more validation errors occurred. 400 0HLRCTBS664E8:00000002
```

My interceptor looks like:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            catchError(error => {
                if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    if (error.status === 401) {
                        return throwError(error.statusText);
                    }
                    const applicationError = error.headers.get('Application-Error');
                    if (applicationError) {
                        console.error(applicationError);
                        return throwError(applicationError);
                    }
                    const serverError = error.error;
                    let modalStateErrors = '';
                    if (serverError && typeof serverError === 'object') {
                        for (const key in serverError) {
                            if (serverError[key]) {
                                modalStateErrors += serverError[key] + '\n';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return throwError(modalStateErrors || serverError || 'Server Error');
                }
            })
        )
    }
}

export const ErrorInterceptorProvide = {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
    multi: true
}
```

My dto class which I used:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "username is required")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "password is required")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "Password should be between 6 and 20 
    characters")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

My Startup class looks like:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
            {
                builder.Run(async context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

                    var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (error != null)
                    {
                        context.Response.AddApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message);
                    }
                });
            });                
        }


        app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();

    }
 }
```

Application error extension method:

```
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void AddApplicationError(this HttpResponse response, string message)
        {
            response.Headers.Add("Application-Error", message);
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Application-Error");
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are having an issue with [automatic 400 responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#automatic-http-400-responses) from your API.

The best way to avoid it, is to suppress this error.

> To disable the automatic 400 behavior, set the
>   SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter property to true. Add the following
>   highlighted code in Startup.ConfigureServices:

This is the included code in the article:

```
services.AddMvc()

.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
.ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
{
    options.SuppressConsumesConstraintForFormFileParameters = true;
    options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
    options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
    options.SuppressMapClientErrors = true;
    options.ClientErrorMapping[404].Link =
        "https://httpstatuses.com/404";
});
```

The microsoft [recommended way in github, is here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8575)

Comment: I tried but it does not worked. Funny part is for displaying single message it works